# CMake - tracing and debugging targets dependencies

Tags: cmake

I have a rather complicated `CMakeLists.txt` file with multiple `add_subdirectory`'s, `add_custom_command`'s, and `add_custom_target`'s. I don't modify any source files. However some binary targets are always rebuilt and it takes valuable time. I have to debug this issue, or write new a `CMakeLists.txt` file from scratch.

Is there a way to get from CMake information about why it rebuilds a particular target at build time?

For example, GNU Make has the `--debug` command line option:

```
Considering target file 'foo.exe'.
Prerequisite 'bar.cpp' is newer than target 'foo.exe'.
Must remake target 'foo.exe'
```

Maybe CMake has something similar? There are `--debug` and `--trace` options, but they seem to be handled at configure time and are not able to say something at build time.

CMake has the `--graphviz` option for that, but it shows only binary targets. No interface, alias, and added dependencies support. There are appropriate tickets in the official tracker:

- *[Interface libraries and --graphviz](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/15638)*
- *[Alias libraries and --graphviz](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/15636)*
- *['add_dependencies' and --graphviz](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/13809)*

Comment: If make has the debug output you need and your code can be build on linux then you can generate the make files with the "Unix Makefiles" generator and use make with the debug option to build your project. Another possibility is to create a dependency tree with the cmake ````--graphviz```` option  [https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html). This can give you a hint about cyclic dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for comment. Unfortunately `--graphviz` shows only binary targets, no INTERFACE_LIBRARY's, no UTILITY's.

Comment: I don't know exactly what it does, but I saw in another thread there's something called [`GLOBAL_DEPENDS_DEBUG_MODE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_gbl/GLOBAL_DEPENDS_DEBUG_MODE.html). Maybe take a look?

Comment: in cmake 3.24, `GLOBAL_DEPENDS_DEBUG_MODE` seems to show dependencies from `add_dependencies`, but doesn't seem to show `INTERFACE` and `ALIAS` targets.

Comment: If you can use the ninja generator, ninja has the `ninja -t deps` command/tool to show dependency information, which might be useful to you. You may also find [Craig Scott's article on "Build Performance Insights"](https://crascit.com/2022/06/24/build-performance-insights/) useful.